# Need help regarding printing urdue/arabic thermal receipt printing using PrinterUtility

Tags: c#, thermal-printer, pos

I am developing in C# a WindowsForm application and directly writing Arbic/Urdue text as string by converting it to utf8 encoding.
I would like to know why I get `?????` instead of text.

My code:

```
 BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.CharSize.Nomarl());
 BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ٹیسٹ سٹرنگ"));
 BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Lf());
 BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, obj.Alignment.Left());
 BytesValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(BytesValue, pf.cutPage());
```

Comment: There's no `PrintUtility` or `PrintExtensions` in the .NET BCL. What are those classes? In any case, POS printers are *not* normal printers. They receive characters from a serial port (real or virtual) and print it using their built-in fonts. To select character sets or fonts, you need to configure the printer itself, or sent escape sequences to set it. The way to do this is described in the printer's manual

Comment: Generating UTF8 bytes from .NET's UTF16 strings isn't going to work unless the printer is configured to use the UTF8 character set.

Comment: Please add the vendor name and model name of the printer you are going to use, as well as its programming manual and device driver information. Depending on the printer, a device driver that can be used as a Windows Desktop page printer may be prepared.

Comment: @kunif, Black Copper BC-100AC

Comment: There seems to be no information about device drivers or ESCPOS command references on the Web. Please ask your printer vendor or reseller for them. [BC100AC Thermal Receipt Printer](http://www.blackcopper.net/thermal-receipt-printers/68-bc100ac-thermal-receipt-printer.html)